# If-else condition compare 2 data from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a php Script:

```
$date1 = $_POST["date1"]; //date from database mysql  
$date2 = $_POST["date2"]; //date form fill from 

$time1 = $_POST["time1"]; //time from database mysql 
$time2 = $_POST["time2"]; //time form fill from
```

examle : data form database

```
$date1 ='03/11/2014';
$time1 = '10:00:00';
```

I want to Validate the form if I enter this value in form (compare that). In the form, I fill :

```
 $date2 ='03/11/2014' and then, '02/11/2014' and then, '04/11/2014'  
    $time2 = '10:00:00' and then, '10:00:10 and then, 09:00:00'
```

the scirpt will compare that, about $date1 with $date2 and $time1 with $time2. So, the result must like this table.

```
No.|date ($date2) | time ($time2)|status |
1. |03/11/2014    | 10:00:10     |valid  |
2. |03/11/2014    | 09:00:00     |invalid|
3. |02/11/2014    | 10:00:10     |invalid|
4. |02/11/2014    | 09:00:00     |invalid|
5. |04/11/2014    | 10:00:00     |valid  |
6. |04/11/2014    | 09:00:00     |valid  |
```

I have make the script below, but I don't get the answer. I think I get wrong in my if script.

```
if ($time2 < $time1 && $date2 < date1){
echo "<script>alert('invalid')</script>" 
} 
else{
echo "<script>alert(valid)</script>" 
}
```

Please help me to solve this. I wasting 2 days to try, but it not solved.

Comment: What are the exact criteria for a valid date? Your question contains irrelevant info, such as that one date was from MySQL and that you're using an if-else statement.

Comment: criteria for a valid like the table.. if date same with date, but the time must above, and then if date above that and time above or under the time ($time1)

Comment: try comparing them as date-time key pair with also date-time keypair with the input

Comment: The criteria in the question is still somewhat unclear, which is probably the source of your difficulty. You can code something only if you can define it clearly and unambiguously. Is the criteria that the date-time from the DB must precede the date-time from the form? If so, update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime()`. Also you have many syntax errors. Fixed those or can try like below.

```
if (strtotime($time2) < strtotime($time1) && strtotime($date2) < strtotime($date1)){
                                                                        /*^^^*/
    echo "<script>alert('invalid')</script>";
                                         /*^^^*/
}
else{
    echo "<script>alert('valid')</script>";
                      /*^^^^^^^*/      /*^^^*/
}
```

Comment: so sory, but this script not help.